# Import Django QuerySet to python list

Tags: python, django, list

I am trying to export my Django QuerySet to a python list but I couldn't achieve it.

**My data structure:**

```
[{'time_stamp': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 30, 22, 0, 37, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'num_avg': 1}, {'time_stamp': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 31, 22, 0, 37, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'num_avg': 2}]
```

**My attempt is:**

```
my_query=MyModell.objects.all().filter(time_stamp__range=('2017-10-01', '2017-10-02')).values('time_stamp').annotate(num_avg=Avg('number')).order_by('time_stamp')

data=[i.num_avg for i in my_query]
```

Unfortunately I got this error message when I tried to retrieve the num.

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'num_avg'
```

My aim is to get a list like this a=[1,2]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably work

Change

```
data=[i.num_avg for i in my_query]
```

to

```
data=[i['num_avg'] for i in my_query]
```

Comment: Sorry for my typo, The real value is num_avg. I edited it. So the problem is actual.

Comment: Can you try data=[i['num_avg'] for i in my_query]?

Comment: Are you sure that your my_query is returning the correct info posted above?

Comment: Oh I missed a typo again, bad day.. Your answer finally solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`QuerySet.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

In your case, you'll want to do as follows:

```
data = MyModell.objects \
    .filter(time_stamp__range=('2017-10-01', '2017-10-02')) \
    .values('time_stamp') \
    .annotate(num_avg=Avg('number')) \
    .order_by('time_stamp') \
    .values_list('num_avg', flat=True)
```

Also of note:  I dropped the `.all()` call.  There's no need for it if you're doing other things after it; `.all()` is implied.